# reinstalling Ubuntu dual-boot goes to initramfs

Tags: initramfs

I inadvertently did some operations on the terminal that resulted in Dual Boot not working anymore.
Hence, I went into Windows disk management and "deleted" Ubuntu from the partitions so that I can reinstall it from USB.
  However, now when I try to choose options to reinstall Ubuntu or to Try Ubuntu before installing, I get the Ubuntu logo and dots filling in white and orange screen but then goes to a black screen with initramfs. Upon typing `exit`, I get a wall of code with something about `Kernel panic`.
    When I push F12 and go into the Bios Setup, I can see some Ubuntu files still there and I read those files don't get saved into the partitions.  How can I delete these files so that Ubuntu is completely erased from my computer so I can reinstall it from scratch?  I have a USB drive with the ubuntu iso file and Universal USB installer.  My machine is a Windows 10 Dell Inspirion 3558 64 bit. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you manually removed whole ubuntu partition but forgot to remove grub loader. And each time when you boot pc - you trigger grub loader first who cant find out  where ubuntu is installed.

Comment: Wise descition would be boot from live cd and go to disk allocation where you need to figure it out where grub is installed. And do installation procedure like for the first time.

Comment: @Reborn I try "try Ubuntu without installing" from my USB which worked before but now getting the same sequence as above.  Do I actually need to use a DVD?  Also, how can I get to disk allocation from the Bios screen (entered pushing F12 key when restarting).

Comment: I found all sorts of grub files from Windows Explorer.  Should I delete all of them?

Comment: For some reason my laptop refuse to boot from usb( i know its working port) so i use dvd. About split partitions... have you ever faced step where ubuntu detects "microsoft mbr" and first option will go as "delete and reinstall ubuntu alongside"? On that step you need to choose the last option "other" which brings you to partitions.you nedd to delete partition where grub is located and create partition.

Comment: Dont try to remove via windows... because there is a high risk of leftover files.

Comment: @reborn, I don't remember that screen but will go through the sequence again.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to manually delete enough Ubuntu-related files in Windows and reinstall from a USB.  I used Windows Explorer to search `grub` and `ubuntu` to do so.